# Inline Ampscript functions aren't visible in Content Builder Preview

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

When adding ampscript functions like `%%=v(@accountName)=%%` into a freeform block they are initially visible but when saved and edited again, the function disappears in the WYSIWYG view and is only editable in the HTML view.  Has anyone else experienced this bug or have a workaround?

Comment: The workaround is to never use the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Well, I guess it's time to get a case open with Marketing Cloud :)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this once you open the WYSIWYG you have a wait a few seconds before clicking into the HTML TAB and it should work. If the WYSWIG window opens and you click too fast everything gets erased. My work around was to just use the HTML only option and avoid the WYSWIG completely.

Comment: Please [do not use a signature](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). *Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers. Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!*